# Python/SQL Server - Subquery inside of a SELECT problem

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I try to make my queries a little bit better and also try to reduce the amont of them I have inside my code.
So I stumbled over subqueries. The thing I want to achieve now is that I SELECT the BankID in my Entity Table and with that I directly want to get the Name of the BankID inside of my Bank Table.

I use Python and SQL Server with a Pooled DB. If i missed something please let me know!

At the moment my code is just getting the ID:

```
import DB_Pool

ms = DB_Pool.Database()

entity_id = 1

entity_data = ms.ExecQuery("SELECT Name,BankID FROM Entity WHERE EntityID = ? AND IsCurrent = 1",(entity_id,))

print(entity_data)
```

This is working fine.

But I cant get my head around on where to add the BankName SELECT with the BankID I got from the Entity Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a `join`. Assuming that `Entity` and `Bank` relate through column `BankID`, that would be:

```
SELECT e.Name entityName, e.BankID, b.Name bankName
FROM Entity e
INNER JOIN Bank b on b.BankID = e.BankID
WHERE e.EntityID = ? AND e.IsCurrent = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for you answere i think this is working fine for me. I just have then another problem, because i am dealing with an Old Database. I need to TRIM and CAST the Return for e.BankID with something like 'CAST(TRIM(['IN' FROM ]e.BankName) AS int)'. I need to remove the Caracters "IN" and cast the rest "0000002" as example to integer. Is this possible?